# Material-UI : Rating Component, change color based on value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design, gatsby

**Goal**

To change color of Ratings ( a material-ui component ) based on the value during hover. For example if I hover on 1rst star, color becomes red, if on 5th star then it becomes green.

[image]

I've tried making a custom component which changes color on hover, like this -

```
const StyledRating = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "#ff6d75",
  },
  iconFilled: {
    color: '#ff6d75',
  },
  iconHover: {
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: "#000",
  },
})(Rating);
```

But it changes all of the icons color.

Can anyone please guide me, how to change specific icons in ratings color based on the value I select or hover on.

[Current sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cwemp?file=/demo.tsx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've formed an answer for typescript people where we need to have declared state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ratings-vksqc?file=/demo.tsx

```
<div className={classes.root}>
      <Rating
        name="hover-feedback"
        value={value}
        precision={1}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          console.log(event, "This is th e event");
          setValue(newValue);
          switch (true) {
            case newValue <= 1: {
              setIconFilled(classes.iconFilled1);
              break;
            }
            case newValue <= 2 && newValue > 1: {
              setIconFilled(classes.iconFilled2);
              break;
            }
            case newValue <= 3 && newValue > 2: {
              setIconFilled(classes.iconFilled3);
              break;
            }
            case newValue <= 4 && newValue > 3: {
              setIconFilled(classes.iconFilled4);
              break;
            }
            case newValue > 4: {
              setIconFilled(classes.iconFilled5);
              break;
            }
          }
        }}
        onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
          switch (true) {
            case newHover <= 1: {
              setIconHover(classes.iconHover1);
              break;
            }
            case newHover <= 2 && newHover > 1: {
              setIconHover(classes.iconHover2);
              break;
            }
            case newHover <= 3 && newHover > 2: {
              setIconHover(classes.iconHover3);
              break;
            }
            case newHover <= 4 && newHover > 3: {
              setIconHover(classes.iconHover4);
              break;
            }
            case newHover > 4: {
              setIconHover(classes.iconHover5);
              break;
            }
          }
        }}
        defaultValue={2}
        icon={<FiberManualRecordIcon fontSize="inherit" />}
        classes={{
          iconFilled: iconFilledVar,
          iconHover: iconHoverVar
        }}
      />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use dynamic style ([Overriding styles with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes))

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    // ...
  },
  'icon-1': { color: 'red' },
  'icon-2': { color: 'coral' },
  'icon-3': { color: 'orange' },
  'icon-4': { color: 'skyblue' },
  'icon-5': { color: 'green' }
});

export default function HoverRating() {
  // ... 
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Rating
        classes={{
          iconHover: classes[`icon-${Math.ceil(hover)}`]
        }}
        //...
      />
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Wow! Works Awesome! Thanks a lot!