# React, Mui Rating Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm recently working on a project using react. I would like to know if there is a way to color the Material-UI component of the rating with custom colors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material-UI : Rating Component, change color based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451658/material-ui-rating-component-change-color-based-on-value)

Answer (score 1):

**Actually, you can have whatever icon shape or colour that you like**

Take a look at this example from [Material UI site](https://material-ui.com/components/rating/):

[image: Edit Material demo]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example

[material-ui.com/components/rating/customize](https://material-ui.com/components/rating/#CustomizedRatings.js)

and create a costm component in your preferred color

smt like this

```
const StyledRating = withStyles({
  iconFilled: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  iconHover: {
    color: 'darkred',
  },
})(Rating);
```

Comment: Thanks...my idea was to give a different color for each iconFilled element. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: most likely yes, can you see this example https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2jymk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/demo.tsx